# Should we rename [bs-johnson] as [b-s-johnson]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[bs-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bs-johnson) refers to the author, B. S. Johnson. Should we rename [bs-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bs-johnson) as [b-s-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b-s-johnson)?

Comment: Not much point in a meta post for this, since the rename can only be done by mods (as the tag names are too similar) and it's an obvious change. Just raise a flag and ask for it to be renamed.

Comment: I've raised a flag, it'll get taken care of when a CM sees it.

Comment: Done. For future reference, a tag with one question, no need to flag it. Just edit (or suggested edit) the question.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I tried, but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, we should rename [bs-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bs-johnson) as [b-s-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b-s-johnson), because that is what we have done with [j-k-rowling](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-k-rowling) instead of [jk-rowling](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling) and [george-r-r-martin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-r-r-martin), instead of [george-rr-martin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-rr-martin).